# How can I find the union on a list of sets in Python?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, set, set-union

This is the input:

```
x = [{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}]
```

and the output should be:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

I tried to use `set().union(x)` but this is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

Answer (score 91):

The signature of [`set.union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.union) is `union(other, ...)`. Unpack sets from your list:

```
In [6]: set.union(*x)
Out[6]: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Comment: warning: do not work on empty list

Comment: set().union(*x) works on empty list